# troubles using pip to install packages in python

Tags: python, import

I am having troubles importing many (but not all!) modules in python.
I am very new to python. I have read up  about setting pythonpath. I did it as this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("pathtomypythoninstallation")
print sys.path
```

still I get error:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

My OS: OS X 10.9.5, using python 3.6

Comment: you can check if `numpy` is installed using `pip show numpy` on the command line.

Comment: Happy numpy worked. But now I try to install mvpa2 from here with command pip install mvpa, or in python import mpva2.suite, http://www.pymvpa.org/examples/searchlight.html. It does not work. Error: 
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mpva2.suite (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mpva2.suite
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: try upgrading your pip installation:    "pip install --upgrade pip"

Comment: I did that already, so I don't know why this always shows up..path mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think you will be more successful using a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) try this on a shell (if you are using python3):

```
$ python3 -m venv myenv
$ source myenv/bin/activate
$ pip install numpy
$ pip install pymvpa2
$ python -c 'import numpy'
```

Remind the prepending $ has to be removed as it only means you should run the command as your usual user.

Comment: I will try now! Do you manage download mvpa2 from my comment above? Never works for me..

Comment: I have added also instructions to install pymvpa2

Comment: Thank you. But: no module called venv. And it seems when I try to install venc same problem. I tried: pip install venv

Comment: That's odd, venv is part of the core python library since 3.3 Are you sure your python version is 3.6?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Numpy library. Enter this in the terminal:

```
pip3 install numpy
```